# Text on UITextview disappears after adding it to a navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitextview

This way the text isn't showing upp

```
ClubViewController *cvc = [[ClubViewController alloc] init];
cvc.title = [self wordAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString * temp = [[DataManager getSharedInstance] getClubInfo:cvc.title onCountry:self.countryName];
[[cvc info] setText:temp];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
[cvc release]
```

This way it does.

```
ClubViewController *cvc = [[ClubViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
    cvc.title = [self wordAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString * temp = [[DataManager getSharedInstance] getClubInfo:cvc.title onCountry:self.countryName];
    [[cvc info] setText:temp];
    [cvc release]
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the XIB file isn't loaded yet. It gets loaded as soon as the view controller is pushed onto the navigation controller. Prior to the view being loaded and the outlets being set `cvc.info` would be pointing to `nil`. So calling `[cvc.info setText:temp];` would do nothing.

But in the second case, the outlet is set. So the same `[cvc.info setText:temp];` has a meaning and the text is set in the view.

**EDIT**

Just to add, the right way to go would be to create a property to store your value and setting the text for the text field in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLoad` like others have opined in the comments.

Comment: So, is there an ideal solution to this? I mean, I don't think setting the text after the TextView is on screen is the best idea, is it?

Also, I had been using the second code until today, when I needed to use a UITabBarController inside the Navigation Controller. Apparently, there's now no way to make it work, regardless of the place where I call the setText method...

Comment: The best solution is to NOT use UI components to store the state of your app.  You need to store the string in question in a property on your view controller and display it in the textField whenever you need to.  This is a very important concept on the iPhone because any time your view is offscreen, it could get unloaded and would need to be ready to load the view and return it to the same state it was at before it was unloaded.

Comment: the controller should know where the model state is and set it in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`